# find google map places with name from coordinates that is points in map

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

i create my google map with coordinates that is comming from my database. 
in my table i have coordinates which i points with google pointer in my asp.net page. but now i wants to search with name of city which i have coordinate of search name in my db and highlight with color in google map 
i have the following code to fetch my db coordinates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
                 {
                     <%--''<%# GetImageFromByte(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Image")) %>' '--%>
                     "title":"Survey",
                     <%--   "title": '<%# Eval("Name") %>',--%>
                     "lat": '<%# Eval("lat") %>',
                     "lng": '<%# Eval("Long") %>',
                     "description": "<div> <img src='' alt='Alternate Text1' /></div>",
                     "image": "<div> <img src='<%#Eval("photo")%>' width='150px' alt='Picture not available for this survey' /></div>",
                     "Name":'<%# Eval("Name")%>',
                     "PhoneNumber":'<%# Eval("PhoneNumber")%>'
                 }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function () {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description+data.image+data.Name+ 
                           '<br/>'+ data.PhoneNumber);

                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

TO deal with this issue, First you have to check if the marker is currently present on the map or not. Use the following method to know if the city under search has the Latitude and Longitude on the Map or not.

This method will return `true` if the `coordinates` of the city under search are present on the map else would return `false`.

```
map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition());
```

Once it returns true, you can assign it with some color.

Hope that helps!!